# [] operator in std::map is giving me segmentation fault

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have a

```
std::map<std::string, myClass*> myMap
```

then I am inserting like follow:

```
if(!myKey.empty())
{
    myMap[myKey] = this;
}
```

This sometime is throwing a segmentation fault.

Why??

Comment: I need to read more carefully. What is 'this'?

Comment: You should give us this code's context. That code isolated works perfectly fine.

Comment: The code is huge, and from the core dump, the software always hangs at this line then goes into the map library

Comment: `myMap` might have been corrupted by some code we can't see. Have you tried debugging this? Could make it easier to determine if that's the case.

Comment: yes and the debugger exits at this line, is there a way to check if myMap is corrupted? how can it be corrupted? any example?

Comment: It might be corrupted by some erroneous low-level memory operation in which you modify an object that is declared next to it. Or, if `myMap` is a member variable, it's containing object might have been freed. Valgrind or a similar tool can also help you identify memory management issues.

Comment: For some reason, people are voting down on my question, I think it is very legit question?!? why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your myMap is no longer accessible. For instance, it might be a reference to a deleted pointer, or, much more probable, a member variable of an already deleted class:

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    selfInsert(std::string myKey) {
      if(!myKey.empty()) {
        myMap[myKey] = this;
      }
    }

  private:
    std::map<std::string, myClass*> myMap;
}

int main()
{
  MyClass *a = new MyClass();
  delete a;
  a->selfInsert();
}
```